# Fresh Ubuntu 13.04 installed, login not working

Tags: installation, unity, gnome, login, gui

Having all sorts of issues with mini.iso, thought it'd save me some time downloading (slow internet) but I simple don't know what packages I need to get.

Anyways, my issue right now is logging into my desktop.  I have the unity version of Ubuntu 13.04 desktop.  I had to manually grab xorg and xserver and lightdm, which 'works', but I can not log into the comp.  What happens is the login screen after accepting my password, will just refresh and ask me to login again.

I can log in in terminal (ctrl+alt+f1), but `startx` does not work.  I get a window popup stating 'failed to load session gnome'. I don't think I have this package, and I can get it installed, but before I attempt it wanted to make sure gnome is required here (dumb question sorry) as it's a 500mb download and will take me a few hours to get.

I feel like I'm going to just grab the normal .iso for 13.04 and go that route because I simply don't' know enough.

This happened the last attempt I tried on this machine, except I was using Kubuntu instead of unity.

Answer (score 0):

I have had something similar happen to me. Look in your home directory using `ls -al`. There should be a file called .Xauthority (its a hidden file). If this file is owned by root this could be causing your problem. You can fix it by using `sudo chown <username>:<username> .Xauthority` to regain ownership of the file or you can rename it `mv .Xauthority .old.Xauthority` and a new file with correct ownership will be created when you login. When I had this problem this worked for me, hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but to no avail.

I think I'm just going to download the full .iso and start from scratch.